# Identify if a name is in a list

Tags: python

```
mens_name = ['Bob', 'Frank', 'John', 'Rob', 'Eric', 'Dan', 'Doug']
current_name = raw_input('Please enter a name: ')
if current_name == mens_name[0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7] or mens_name[0].upper():
    print 'I know that name.\n'
```

is there an easier way of doing this, or do I have put all of those or's?

Thanks,
G

Comment: Note, that `0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7` is always `1`. And `current_name == mens_name[0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7] or mens_name[0].upper()` is always `True`, because `mens_name[0].upper()` is `True`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `in` keyword:

```
if current_name in mens_name:
```

Comment: It is not only easier, it actually works, unlike your snippet. But soon pointed this out in a comment.

Comment: Pleas accept the answer if you consider it helpful.

Comment: mens_name = ['Bob', 'Frank', 'John', 'Rob', 'Eric', 'Dan', 'Doug']
current_name = raw_input('Please enter a name: ')
if current_name in mens_name or current_name in mens_name.upper():
    print 'I know that name.' Do i have to split this into two?

Comment: @user3264459 you cant call upper on list instance but can on string: `if name.upper() in mens_name:`

Comment: so would I create a new string like mname = mens_name?

Comment: @user3264459 here answer to you question, if you need list with upper case names:http://stackoverflow.com/a/21539256/1099876